# Create a new instance of class on calling a method

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have a Console Application which is injecting all the services through the constructor. I am also creating and initializing a Dictionary in the Constructor of my data access class.

I am calling the data access method from my main class but I wanted to create a new instance of data access class and therefore dictionary whenever I call the method GetData().

```
public class Startup
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        serviceProvider.GetService<MyService>().Start();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IMyServiceDataAccess, MyServiceDataAccess>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<MyService>();
    }
 }
```

MyServiceClass:

```
private readonly IMyServiceDataAccess _dataAccess;
public MyService(IMyServiceDataAccess dataAccess)
{
    _dataAccess = dataAccess;
}

public void Start()
{
     var data = _dataAccess.GetData();
}
```

DataAccess interface

public interface IMyServiceDataAccess
   {
      List GetData();
   }

DataAccess class:

```
Dictionary<bool,List<int> dict;
public MyServiceDataAccess()
{
    dict = new Dictionary<bool,List<int>>()
}

public List<int> GetData()
{
    // have to access the above dict and everytime I need new instance 
    // of this dict
}
```

This is a multithreaded application hence multiple threads can share the dictionary. One way is that I create new instance of dictionary in get data method every time it is called.

Comment: Why are you using a field when you need only a variable inside `GetData()`? Do you use `dict` in any other method?

Comment: The way you registered your services with `AddTransient` will prevent your dictionary from being shared. Any time a thread requests an instance of `MyServiceDataAccess`, it will get a new instance of the class with its own copy of your `Dictionary<bool, List<int>>` object.

Comment: What? This is an X-Y Problem, your assuming that "One way is that I create new instance of dictionary in get data method every time it is called."  Chances are don't need to do anything with the dictionary, you just need to call ToArray inside the GetData, so the List of ints isn't attached to the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you want your `Dictionary<bool, List<int>>` object to be shared, I assume you did not intend to inject the `MyServiceDataAccess` as a transient object. Either make the dictionary on the object `static`, or inject it as a `Singleton` below.

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IMyServiceDataAccess, MyServiceDataAccess>();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<MyService>();
}
```

Whether or not you should do this depends on your data layer, for example, [EntityFramework Core recommends to inject DbContexts with a Scoped lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#implicitly-sharing-dbcontext-instances-across-multiple-threads-via-dependency-injection).

At that point, you could update your `GetData` method to reinitialize your `Dictionary` in its method call.... but you have multiple threads that could be calling this method at the same time, and if your `Dictionary` is `static` or you're using a `Singleton`, you're going to run into issues with modifying the `Dictionary` and trying to use it across different threads. You would want to use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) instead, which is thread-safe. However, why do you need to share this `Dictionary` across threads if you're just re-initializing it every call anyway? The only answers that will achieve the solution you asked for will either have an unreliable `Dictionary`, or you will have to gate your `GetData` call and negate any point in sharing the `Dictionary` to begin with.

I've made some assumptions with this answer because you didn't clearly describe the problem you're having, just the details of the solution you're looking for which is easy to implement but logically has a lot of problems. The goal of this answer was to highlight those issues and hopefully lead you in a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing the actual question, but I assume you are asking how can you cache the same data, without connecting to the external database every time.

You can use ObjectCache for that. An example:

```
private ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

public MyServiceDataAccess()
{

}

public List<int> GetData()
{
    string data = cache["someKey"] as List<int>;

    if (data == null)
    {
        //fetch the actual data
        data = GetMyData();
        cache.Set("someKey", data);
    }

    return data
}
```